# How to skip or not apply cellpainter for a specific cell in NatTable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, nattable, nebula

I am using NatTable tree table in my project. In that table one column is not applicable for parent element. It is applicable only for children. The column uses checkbox CellPainter. Since the parent row does not have that attribute I don't want to apply the cellpainter of the column to that. Is it possible to skip that CellPainter for specific row or cell.

Thanks in Advance,
Arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to skip. You have to be more explicit in the way you register the painters. Either register the checkbox cell painter only on cells that are applicable, or override the painter configuration for the other cells.

Comment: Is it possible to have both ColumnOverideAccumulator and CellOverrideAccumulator at the same time.

Comment: You need to combine them using the `AggregateConfigLabelAccumulator` as described here: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html#architecture_labels_aggregate

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sir. I have assigned label using column based accumulator and registered cell painter to that label. Now will it be possible to remove that label only in the specific cell of that column.

Comment: You can implement a custom `IConfigLabelAccumulator` that you combine with the `ColumnLabelAccumulator` and then perform the check and remove the label again. But I would not suggest this as adding and then checking and removing is not optimal. Instead implement a custom `IConfigLabelAccumulator` that only adds a label if it is needed.